# Advanced Reload Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need a better reload command for my bot because the one that I use is meant for a command handler that isn't advanced and can't read through more than one directory. How do I change my reloader so that it is able to go through all my directories and find the command requested for a reload?

```js
if (!args.length) return message.channel.send(`Hey <@${message.author.id}>!`, embed01);
const commandName = args[0].toLowerCase();
const command = message.client.commands.get(commandName)
    || message.client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

if (!command) return message.channel.send(`There is no command with name or alias \`${commandName}\`, ${message.author}!`);
        
delete require.cache[require.resolve(`../../commands//${command.name}`)];


try {
    const newCommand = require(`./${command.name}.js`);
    message.client.commands.set(newCommand.name, newCommand);
    message.channel.send(`Hey <@${message.author.id}>!`, embed02);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.channel.send(`There was an error while reloading a command \`${command.name}\`:\n\`${error.message}\``);
}
```

The line that has the delete area is what I need to know before I do my new command creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to export the path of the command in your file (create a `command.path` variable that you can re-use to delete the resolve cache). Here is an example bot using this way: https://github.com/Androz2091/AtlantaBot.

You can also try to reconstruct the path of the command dynamically. For example, if you have a "moderation" folder in your "commands" folder, you can use:

```js
delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./commands/${command.category}/${command.name}.js`)];
```

Comment: I was looking at the AtlantaBot reload command, and I’m gonna be honest that is close to what I am exactly wanting, I’ll give it a try and I will let you know how it works! Thank you for your response.